# What is a good way to track background events in Android without inflating session numbers?

Tags: android, session, background, analytics, flurry

Right now I use Flurry for all my in app analytics needs. I'm starting to add features involving services and broadcast receivers. I want to track events within these components, but I don't want to start a new session in Flurry based on these passive events. From what I can tell, the only way to track events in Flurry is to track them between the start and end of a session. Essentially I want to see if people using the new features boost my session count.

One idea I'm thinking about is passing the passive event parameters in my intents to the Activities. Then including those with every active event that normally gets sent to Flurry for that session.

Is this a good approach? Is there a better way with Flurry or even a better tool?

**Update**

I got a response from Flurry, but not the one I was hoping for

> We currently do not support the sending of events from within a BroadcastReceiver on Android. The events must be logged from within the confines of a session, and the sessions are dependent on Contexts.
>   Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to have a Service or an IntentService that you can call with event data that you want to send to Flurry. The service could cache, summarize, queue and do whatever you need before sending the data and it wouldn't depend on an Activity running.

You would still need to start a session but you could just have one long session instead of starting a new one for each event.